# "mod_mono and xsp have different versions" error

Tags: opensuse, mono, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to start a test MVC4 application on Mono 2.10

```
$ xsp --version
xsp2.exe 2.10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc.
Minimalistic web server for testing System.Web

$ mod-mono-server4 --version  
mod-mono-server4.exe 2.10.2.0
(c) (c) 2002-2011 Novell, Inc.
Mod_mono backend for XSP
```

When I start `mod-mono-server4` and perform a request I get this

```
$ mod-mono-server4 --port 8080
mod-mono-server4
mod-mono-server4
Listening on port: 8080
Listening on address: 0.0.0.0
Root directory: /path/to/htdocs
Hit Return to stop the server.
mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 71
mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 71
System.InvalidOperationException: mod_mono and xsp have different versions. Expected '9', got 71
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoRequest.GetInitialData () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoRequest..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.Socket client) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.RequestReader..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.Socket client) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.InnerRun (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Mono.WebServer.ModMonoWorker.Run (System.Object state) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I have [read](http://pointbeing.net/weblog/2009/01/more-mono-mod-mono-and-apache.html) that it could be due to a version conflict between `xsp` and `apache2-mod_mono` packages, but I reinstalled them from the Novell's official repository, forcing reinstallation from YaST, and then rebooted. The error persists.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly this was a bug in mod_mono or xsp (can't remember which). I suggest you move to a more recent version of mono, xsp and mod_mono in the 2.10.* series. If in any doubt you can compile from source. I wrote a [mono installer script](https://github.com/firegrass/mono-installer-script) (for Ubuntu) but might be of some help.

Comment: Do you know more about this bug? Your installer script is not for Mono 3.x unfortunately.